# Retrieve a complete list of all Categories, Sub Categories, Sub Sub Categories, etc. in only one SQL query

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have following table structure and data in MySQL

```
CatID  CatName     ParentCatID
-------------------------------
1       Shirts        NULL
2       Short Sleev    1
3       Long Sleev     1
4       Collarless     2
5       Collar         2
6       Collarless     3
7       Collar         3
8       Square Cut     4
9       Round Cut      4
10      Square Cut     6
11      Round Cut      6
```

Return data that I want is something like this:

```
Shirts > Short Sleev
Shirts > Long Sleev
Shirts > Short Sleev > Collarless
Shirts > Short Sleev > Collar
Shirts > Long Sleev > Collarless
Shirts > Long Sleev > Collar
Shirts > Short Sleev > Collarless > Square Cut
Shirts > Short Sleev > Collarless > Round Cut
Shirts > Short Sleev > Collar > Square Cut
Shirts > Short Sleev > Collar > Round Cut
```

How can we get these data using one single SQL query in MySQL?

Comment: Are you aware that you have spelling errors in your database?  It is "sleeve" and "color".

Comment: Hmm I see I have misspelled Sleeve and Collar and Collarless. Thanks for pointing out. It is not corrected.

Answer (score 5):

Not really an answer, but a dirty fix I've used in the past in PHP is something like this:

```
$categories = array();

$sql = "SELECT CatID, CatName, ParentCatID FROM TableName";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $parent = intval($row['ParentCatId']);
    if (!isset($categories[$parent])) {
        $categories[$parent] = array();
    }
    $categories[$parent][] = $row;
}
```

This will then give you an array of categories and sub-categories that you can iterate over with a recursive function. Something like:

```
function build_categories($parent, $categories) {
    if (isset($categories[$parent]) && count($categories[$parent])) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($categories[$parent] as $category) {
            echo '<li><a href="#">' . $category['CatName'] . '</a>';
            echo build_categories($category['id'], $categories);
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
$menu = build_categories(0, $categories);
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) and [Storing Hierarchical Data in a Database](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I will check them out.

Comment: Could you add the essence of these articles to your answer? In the current form it is not much more than a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I need this as dropdown list with hierarchy.. So I have used the above code and did some changes. The result meet my requirement. I like to share this to you.

```
$category_string = "";
function build_categories_options($parent, $categories, $level) {
    global $category_string;
    if (isset($categories[$parent]) && count($categories[$parent])) {
        $level .= " - ";
        foreach ($categories[$parent] as $category) {
            $opt_value = substr($level.$category['CatName'],3);
            $category_string .= '<option value="'.$category['CatID'].'">'.$opt_value.'</option>';
            build_categories_options($category['CatID'], $categories, $level);
        }
        $level = substr($level, -3);
    }
    return $category_string;
}
$category_options = build_categories_options(0, $categories, '');
$category_options = '<select name="sel_category" id="sel_category">'.$category_options.'</select>';
```

Then use the echo statement to print anywhere in the page.

```
<?php echo $category_options; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this sample. I have already implemented recursive algorithm to retrieve the list of categories with all sub categories but I want this to be performed at database level so that MySQL will return the list in one simple query or we can define a view that will return complete listing.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think MySQL has support for tree-like structures (as opposite to Oracle, for instance).

If you know the maximum depth of your tree, you can do something with joins... If you don't, it'll be harder.

You can take a look at the article [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), for instance.

If you only have a few lines in your table, a potentially good solution would be to just "`select *`", and to manipulate all this in PHP.

Comment: That is exactly what we are doing currently. But the want to spare myself from the trouble of maintaining such extra PHP code if possible.